# html2pdf error while converting to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, font-face, html2pdf

I have the following code:

```
<?php session_start();
ob_start(); 
// on vérifie toujours qu'il s'agit d'un membre qui est connecté
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { 
   // si ce n'est pas le cas, on le redirige vers l'accueil
   header ('Location: ../index.php'); 
   exit();  
}  
require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); 
mysql_select_db( $database_localhost ); ?>
 <page backtop="50mm"  backbottom="30mm" > 
    <page_header> <font face="arial">
<?php $sql="SELECT `entete`, `pieddepage` FROM `entete` INNER JOIN `courrier` ON `entete`.`id` = `courrier`.`code_entete` WHERE `courrier`.`code_lettre`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courrier'])."'" ;
 $msg= $_POST['msg'];
$result= mysql_query($sql);
$donnees=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ;
echo $donnees['entete'] ;  ?>       </font>       
    </page_header> 
    <page_footer> <font face="arial">
<?php echo $donnees['pieddepage'] ;  ?>     
</font>   
    </page_footer> 
    <font face="arial">
    <?php echo '<font face="Arial">'.$_POST['editor1'].'</font>' ; ?></font>
 </page> 
<?php $content=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
   require_once('html2pdf.class.php');
   $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
   $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$path= 'courriers';
if(file_exists($path)) 
{ 
mkdir($path.'/'.$_GET['n_doss']); 
}
else
{
mkdir($path);
mkdir($path.'/'.$_GET['n_doss']); 
}
  $html2pdf->Output($path.'/'.$_GET['n_doss'].'/'.$_POST['nom_courrier'].'-'.date('d-m-Y').'.pdf', 'F');
  $url=$path.'/'.$_GET['n_doss'].'/'.$_POST['nom_courrier'].'-'.date('d-m-Y').'.pdf';
$sql="INSERT INTO `courrier-envoye` SET
qui = '".$_SESSION['login']."',
quoi = '".$_POST['nom_courrier']."',
quand = '".date('Y-m-d')."',
n_doss= '".$_GET['n_doss']."',
url= '".$url."'";
$req=mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$sql); 


 header('Location: '.$url);

?>
```

In fact it says to me:

TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: verdana

But the thing is that I never put somewhere in my code
something like `<font face='verdana'>`

So I really do not know where does this trouble come from.

Receive all my Utmost Respect.

Kind Regards.

SP

Comment: Verdana's a default font for a lot of things. Just because it's not explicitly listed doesn't mean it can't be used automatically.

Comment: but I've put everywhere something like that  <?php echo '<font face="Arial">'.$_POST['editor1'].'</font>' ; ?></font>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this one. may be it helps.

[Make font for HTML2PDF](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf%3aen%3av3%3afont)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been looking for something like that for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

1.convert any verdana.ttf font file to cp-1252 encoding in http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/

2.drop the encoded file into the fonts directory in html2pdf or tcpdf or fpdf
code for pdf convertion

1. `$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');`

$root_directory="/your root directory to pdf convertion package like tcpdf,html2pdf,fpdf/";

```
$html2pdf->addFont('verdana', '', ''.$root_directory.'/fonts/source-sans-pro.light.php');

//use your font-family:verdana into the html tag in $content 

$content="<b style='font-family:verdana'>hello</b>";

$html2pdf->writeHTML($content);

$html2pdf->Output();
```

check your pdf file